# Reading signed 16 bit data in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been banging my head to solve this:

I received a raw data from an embeded device. From the documentation, the way to read it into a single value is:

> Every two bytes of data can be combined to a single raw wave value.Its value is a signed 16-bit integer that ranges from -32768 to 32767. The first byte of the Value represents the high-order byte of the twos-compliment value, while the second byte represents the low-order byte. To reconstruct the full raw wave value, simply shift the first byte left by 8 bits, and bitwise-or with the
>   second byte.

`short raw = (Value[0]<<8) | Value[1];`

One of the 2 bytes that I received is "ef". When I used the bitwise operation above the result does not seems right as I noticed I never get a single negative value (its ECG data, negative values are normal). I believe using Javascript to do this is not straight forward.
The way I did it was like this:

```
var raw = "ef"; // just to show one. Actual one is an array of this 2 bytes but in string.
var value = raw.charAt(0) << 8 | raw.charAt(1)
```

Please Advice. Thanks!

EDIT:

I also did like this:

```
let first = new Int8Array(len); // len is the length of the raw data array
let second = new Int8Array(len);
let values = new Int16Array(len) // to hold the converted value

for(var i=0; i<len ; i++)
{
   //arr is the array that contains the every two "characters"
   first[i] = arr[i].charAt(0);
   second[i] = arr[i].charAt(1);
   values[i] = first[i] << 8 | second[i];  
}
```

But still all is positive result. no negative. Can someone verify if I am doing this correctly, just in case maybe the values are actually all positive :p

Comment: Just to make things clear, do you know what value 'ef' is supposed to be ? If it is hexadecimal value, then 'ef' is **one** byte.

Comment: I mean, you are trying to mangle the first half of the only byte with the second half of the same byte. Doesn't seem what you are supposed to do here.

Comment: thats what the documentation lacking of. No idea whats the data type. So I assume that its not hex.

Comment: can you receive a string like 'st' ? Or with anything else than `0123456789abcdef` ?

Comment: `assume that its not hex` don't make assumptions, look at the data you are receiving, if you don't see anything outside of 0-9A-F then it is likely a hex string

Comment: note: strings in javascript are not ascii encoded, they are UCS-2 or UTF-16

Comment: note 2: `'ef'.charAt(0)` is the string `'e'` - probably not what you want

Comment: `ef` as you attempted to "decode" is `0110010101100110` which is positive ... all negative values would have "special" characters as the first of the pair (I mean, like `À` or `È` etc) but really, if that's a binary data stream, how is it being "converted" to a string? that's the important consideration

Comment: note that the 'ef' is the value received by the watch over the network. in the server buffer it is ef after that sent to database as 'ef' @JaromandaX so i should use charCodeAt instead? please bear with me

Comment: charCodeAt is clearly more correct than charAt.

Comment: @JaromandaX let say it is actually a hex string, should I just simply combine the 'ef' with the next two characters in order to do the bitwise operation required?

Comment: if it's a hexString ... `var numbers = raw.match(/..../g).map(x => parseInt(x, 16)).map(v => v > 32767 ? v - 65536 : v);` will give you an array of signed 16 bit numbers

Answer (score 2):

You can use property that the string is already 16 bit and then make it signed.
Also instead of reading 8bit at time just read one unsigned 16bit using charCodeAt.

```
var raw = "\u00ef"; //original example
var buf = new Int16Array(1);
buf[0] = raw.charCodeAt(0); //now in the buf[0] is typed 16 bit integer
//returns 239, for \uffef returns -17
```

```js
var raw = "\uffef"; //original example
var buf = new Int16Array(1);
buf[0] = raw.charCodeAt(0); //now in the buf[0] is typed 16 bit integer
console.log(buf[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

It's two's complement: Check the top bit of the high byte - byte[high]>>7. If it's 0, do byte[top]<<8 | byte[low]. If it is one, do -((byte[top]^0xff)<<8 | byte[low]^0xff) - 1. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement for an explanation.

Also check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays. It has Int16 arrays which is what you want. It might be a ton faster.

Answer (score 0):

For first byte take two's complement first then shift by 8 bit

```
let x = raw.charCodeAt(0); //ASCII value of first character
```

then flip x for 1's complement and add +1 for 2's complement and finally do

```
var value = x << 8 | bytevalueof(raw.charCodeAt(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a question about the [raw wave data coming from a Neurosky Mindwave Mobile EEG headset](http://developer.neurosky.com/docs/doku.php?id=thinkgear_communications_protocol#raw_wave_value_16-bit).

You should find three values in the buffer when you read from the device. Perform this operation on the second two to get a correct reading:

```
    var b = reader.buffer(3);
    var raw = b[1]*256 + b[2];
    if(raw >= 32768) {
      raw = raw - 65536;
    }
```

Comment: Where do you know the data source `Neurosky Mindwave Mobile EEG`? In the question only medical-device `ECG` is mentioned. Is the source device important?

Comment: The person took the `short raw = ...` formula from here: http://developer.neurosky.com/docs/doku.php?id=thinkgear_communications_protocol#raw_wave_value_16-bit

Answer (score 0):

Use [`TypedArray.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray).

In your case the array is `Int16Array`. You will need to provide the optional [`mapFn` argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and use `charCodeAt` to convert each 16-bit element to an unsigned number, which is then recast as a signed number by `Int16Array`.

```
var bytes = "\u0001\uffff";
var array = Int16Array.from(bytes, c => c.charCodeAt(0));
```

```js
var bytes = "\u0001\uffff";
var array = Int16Array.from(bytes, c => c.charCodeAt(0));
console.log(array[0], array[1]);
// should output 1, -1
```